# improve performance in file IO in C

Tags: c, performance, file, file-io, io

I need to write bulk of integers to a file after performing heap operations on them, one by one. I am trying to merge sorted files into a single file. As of now, I am writing to file after every operation. I am using min heap to merge files.

My questions are -

1. When performing file write, is disk accessed every time a file write is made or chunks of memory blocks are written at a time?
2. Will it improve performance if I'll take output of heap in an array of say size 1024 or may be more and then perform a write at once?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT- Will using setbuffer() help? I feel it should help for certain extend.

Comment: How much data do you really have. Megabytes (then it does not matter much) or petabytes (then it matters a lot, and you need to benchmark).

Comment: The worst case that I have tried till now is around 10 GB data distributed among 200000 file.

Comment: On which operating system, which file system, which hardware, what kind of disks (SSD?), how much RAM?

Comment: It's a laptop. Linux, 4GB ram, SATA HDD, ext4, core 2 duo processor.

Comment: Have you considered mmaping the file, I have always got much better performance with mmap and memcpy

Comment: Post code and machine details.

Comment: its a 250 - 300 line C code, so i don't think its good to post here. And machine details are mentioned in comments above.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. When performing file write, is disk accessed every time a file write is made 
or chunks of memory blocks are written at a time?
```

No. Your output isn't written until the output buffer is full. You can force a write with `fflush` to flush output streams causing an immediate write, but otherwise, output is buffered.

```
other 1. Will it improve performance if I'll take output of heap in an array of 
say size 1024 or may be more and then perform a write at once?
```

If you are not exhausting the heap, then no, you are not going to gain significant performance putting the storage on the stack, etc.. Buffering is always preferred, but if you store all the data in an array and then call write, you still have the same size output buffer to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

> When performing file write, is disk accessed every time a file write
>   is made or chunks of memory blocks are written at a time?

This is up to the kernel. Buffers are flushed when you call `fsync()` on the file descriptor. `fflush()` only flushes the data buffered in the `FILE` structure, it doesn't flush the kernel buffers.

> Will it improve performance if I'll take output of heap in an array of
>   say size 1024 or may be more and then perform a write at once?

I made tests some time ago to compare the performance of `write()` and `fwrite()` against a custom implementation, and it turns out you can gain a fair speedup by calling `write()` directly with large chunks. This is actually what `fwrite()` does, but due to the infrastructure it has to maintain, it is slower than a custom implementation. As for buffer size, 1024 is certainly too small. 8K or something would perform better.

Comment: Good answer, but note it is also up to the C library you are using, not just the kernel how buffering works

Answer (score 0):

It is operating system and implementation specific.

On most Linux systems -with a good filesystem like Ext4- the kernel will try hard to avoid disk accesses by caching a lot of file system data. See [linuxatemyram](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

But I would still recommend avoiding making too much of IO operations, and have some buffering (if using [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) routines, pass buffers of several dozens of kilobytes to [fwrite(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html) and use [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) and [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) with care; alternatively use direct syscalls like [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) or [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with buffers of e.g. 64Kbytes...)

BTW, using perhaps the [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) syscall might marginally help performance (if used wisely).

In reality, the bottleneck is often the hardware. Use RAM filesystems (`tmpfs`) or fast SSD disks if you can.

On Windows systems (which I never used), I have no idea, but the general intuition is that some buffering should help.