# Improving IO performance for merging two files in C

Tags: c, performance, io

I wrote a function which merges two large files (`file1,file2`) into a new file (`outputFile`).
Each file is a line based format while entries are separated by \0 byte. Both files have the same amount of null bytes.

One example file with two entries could look like this    `A\nB\n\0C\nZ\nB\n\0`

```
   Input:
   file1: A\nB\0C\nZ\nB\n\0
   file2: BBA\nAB\0T\nASDF\nQ\n\0
   Output
   outputFile: A\nB\nBBA\nAB\0C\nZ\nB\nT\nASDF\nQ\n\0

FILE * outputFile = fopen(...);
setvbuf ( outputFile  , NULL , _IOFBF , 1024*1024*1024 )
FILE * file1 = fopen(...); 
FILE * file2 = fopen(...); 
int c1, c2;
while((c1=fgetc(file1)) != EOF) {
    if(c1 == '\0'){
        while((c2=fgetc(file2)) != EOF && c2 != '\0') {
            fwrite(&c2, sizeof(char), 1, outputFile);
        }
        char nullByte = '\0';
        fwrite(&nullByte, sizeof(char), 1, outputFile);
    }else{
        fwrite(&c1, sizeof(char), 1, outputFile);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to improve this IO performance of this function? I increased the buffer size of `outputFile` to 1 GB by using `setvbuf`. Would it help to use `posix_fadvise` on file1 and file2?

Comment: I would say two things. FIrst, I've always thought that `write` is faster than `fwrite`. Second, do not write every single byte to a file. Make your own intermediate buffer and write to file big chunks of data.

Comment: Make your code readable.

Comment: @GMichael thanks for your advice. fwrite should be buffered. Do you think that the function call it self is critical?

Comment: Why you need `file1Char` ? Declare `c1` and `c2` as `char`

Comment: @martins Read what is said about `fwrite`: Writes count of objects from the given array buffer to the output stream stream. The objects are written as if by reinterepreting each object as an array of unsigned char and **calling fputc size times** for each object to write those unsigned chars into stream, in order. The file position indicator for the stream is advanced by the number of characters written.

Comment: @Inline I added your changes. Thanks.

Comment: @GMichael I will try write using my own buffer. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: @martins if you will write just one char, I think it is better to use `fputc`.

Comment: Note: `fgetc` returns `int`! `c1` and `c2` must be `int` also, because you need to accommodate all byte values **and** EOF.

Comment: Also: Cast in `c2 != (int) '\0'` is pointless, because all single character constants are already `int` in C.

Comment: since your program is single threaded you can try fread_unlocked and fwrite_unlocked, Read data in bulk and write in bulk will improve performance.

Comment: If the format is fixed at "one byte, newline, one byte, null" you can omit the `if` test after every read. Or read 4 bytes at a time and pass the two/three interesting bytes on to the output stream.

Comment: `fgetc()` is a function. `getc()` *may* be implemented as a macro, which *could* be faster in this case.

Comment: Use `fread` and `fwrite` with buffer at least 512 bytes. This will be much faster than `fgetc`.

Comment: *One example file with two entries could look like this* `A\nB\0C\nZ\nB\0` : Is that an input line or an output line? (you need to describe both)

Comment: @joop I added an example input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing IO character-by-character.  That is going to be needlessly and painfully S-L-O-W, even with buffered streams.

Take advantage of the fact that your data is stored in your files as NUL-terminated strings.

Assuming you're alternating nul-terminated strings from each file, and running on a POSIX platform so you can simply `mmap()` the input files:

```
typedef struct mapdata
{
    const char *ptr;
    size_t bytes;
} mapdata_t;

mapdata_t mapFile( const char *filename )
{
    mapdata_t data;
    struct stat sb;

    int fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY );
    fstat( fd, &sb );

    data.bytes = sb.st_size;

    /* assumes we have a NUL byte after the file data 
       If the size of the file is an exact multiple of the
       page size, we won't have the terminating NUL byte! */
    data.ptr = mmap( NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0 );
    close( fd );
    return( data );
}

void unmapFile( mapdata_t data )
{
    munmap( data.ptr, data.bytes );
}

void mergeFiles( const char *file1, const char *file2, const char *output )
{
    char zeroByte = '\0';

    mapdata_t data1 = mapFile( file1 );
    mapdata_t data2 = mapFile( file2 );

    size_t strOffset1 = 0UL;
    size_t strOffset2 = 0UL;

    /* get a page-aligned buffer - a 64kB alignment should work */
    char *iobuffer = memalign( 64UL * 1024UL, 1024UL * 1024UL );

    /* memset the buffer to ensure the virtual mappings exist */
    memset( iobuffer, 0, 1024UL * 1024UL );

    /* use of direct IO should reduce memory pressure - the 1 MB
       buffer is already pretty large, and since we're not seeking
       the page cache is really only slowing things down */
    int fd = open( output, O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_DIRECT, 0644 );

    FILE *outputfile = fdopen( fd, "wb" );
    setvbuf( outputfile, iobuffer, _IOFBF, 1024UL * 1024UL );

    /* loop until we reach the end of either mapped file */
    for ( ;; )
    {
        fputs( data1.ptr + strOffset1, outputfile );
        fwrite( &zeroByte, 1, 1, outputfile );

        fputs( data2.ptr + strOffset2, outputfile );
        fwrite( &zeroByte, 1, 1, outputfile );

        /* skip over the string, assuming there's one NUL
           byte in between strings */
        strOffset1 += 1 + strlen( data1.ptr + strOffset1 );
        strOffset2 += 1 + strlen( data2.ptr + strOffset2 );

        /* if either offset is too big, end the loop */
        if ( ( strOffset1 >= data1.bytes ) ||
             ( strOffset2 >= data2.bytes ) )
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose( outputfile );

    unmapFile( data1 );
    unmapFile( data2 );       
}
```

I've put in no error checking at all.  You'll also need to add the proper header files.

Note also that the file data is assumed to **NOT** be an exact multiple of the system page size, thus ensuring that there's a NUL byte mapped after the file contents.  If the size of the file is an exact multiple of the page size, you'll have to `mmap()` an additional page after the file contents to ensure that there's a NUL byte to terminate the last string.

Or you can rely on there being a NUL byte as the last byte of the file's contents.  If that ever turns out to not be true, you'll likely get either a SEGV or corrupted data.

Comment: – 1 for using POSIX-specific `mmap`. The question does not call or warrant for it.

Comment: @rubenvb Really?  Is it really that hard for you to replace `mmap()` with something like Windows `CreateFileMapping()`?  It's even encapsulated in a separate set of functions to make it simple.  Here's a link if you need help:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @rubenvb: And even if there wasn't an alternative for non-posix systems... posix systems are still a major use case.

Comment: I was implying `fread` might do an equally fine job, as it most probably uses `mmap` under the hood. And "posix systems are still a major use case" is neither specified nor implied anywhere in the question, whereas "C" is.

Comment: @rubenvb I'd love to see your answer that uses `fread()` - and can handle arbitrary-length strings from the input files.  Also, you're flat-out **WRONG** in stating my use of POSIX deserves a downvote.  The question flat out asks "Would it help to use **posix_fadvise** on file1 and file2?"  Please explain how you'd use **posix_fadvise** on a non-POSIX platform.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is a pretty interesting solution. Thanks a lot for it. 
I experienced slow downs using mmap one large files that do not fit in memory which is the case here. Do you think this might be a problem at this solution?

Comment: @martins Files that are too large to fit in memory certainly can have issues with `mmap()`.  When that happens, the solution has to be more complex.  You can do rolling `munmap()` of the start of the mapped file as you read through the data.  You can also try mapping (on Linux) with the `MAP_NORESERVE` and/or `MAP_HUGETLB` options.  I'll also add some options to the answer for the output file that will reduce memory pressure.

Comment: @martins I added a way to use `DIRECT_IO` on the output file - that should reduce the use of the page cache.  If you still have problems with `mmap()`, that's probably not the best way to go for your problem since your data files are so large.  If you have a known max length string in your input files, you can use "normal" stream IO, try using the `open( ... O_DIRECT` ); fdopen(), `setvbuf()` on the input files.  Just be aware that direct IO has some restrictions on IO size and buffer alignment, and may not work on your filesystem(s), depending on what they are (assuming Linux).

Answer (score 0):

- you are using two function calls per character, (one for input, one for output) Function calls are slow (they pollute the instruction pipeline)
- fgetc() and fputc have their getc() / putc() counterparts, which are (can be) implemented as macros, enabling the compiler to inline the *entire loop*, except for the reading/writing of buffers , twice per 512 or 1024 or 4096 characters processed. (these will invoke system calls, but these are inevitable anyway)
- using read/write instead of buffered I/O will probably not be worth the effort, the extra bookkeeping wil make your loop *fatter* (btw: using fwrite() to write one character is certainly wastefull, same for write())
- *maybe* a larger output buffer could help, but I wouldnt count on that.

Answer (score -2):

If you can use threads, make one for file1 and another for file2.

Make the `outputFile` as big as you need, then make thread1 write the file1 into `outputFile`.

While thread2 seek it's output of `outputFile` the the length of file1+1, and write file2

**Edit:**

**It's not a correct answer for this case**, but to prevent confusions I'll let it here.

More discusion I found about it: [improve performance in file IO in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576740/improve-performance-in-file-io-in-c)

Comment: threading really doesn't improve IO. Because IO is the slowest operation and it sequential. You can't paralelizeze IO on the same disk..

Comment: Well if we have non-blocking byte file we should be able to write it. It's this right?

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but I am pretty confident that disk access is sequential, regardless of what sectors you access. Speedup is made by using OS buffers, memory mapped files etc., not by reading/writing in multiple threads.

Comment: The writes will be buffered if you don't force write with fflush, to flush output streams. So the OS will let you write in paralel and when buffer fills up will write the blocks to the disk.
Extracted from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576740/improve-performance-in-file-io-in-c

Comment: no, you are mixing facts. The OS won't let you write in parallel to the same  buffer. Each write will have it's own internal buffer. And then the writes of the buffers to the disk will be sequenced.